# Setup page for a suite

Tags: selenium, fitnesse

I have a number of "smoketests" that are simple selenium-scripts (2-5 lines) that are run with Xebium/Fitnesse. I have now gotten into the problem that I need to start a "reset-job" before my suite runs since some of the tests need to alter some data, and when the data are alterd, the test doesn't run anymore.

I'd basically would like to create a testpage, that are guarantied to run before the suite and that will run a xebium-table to setup the site.

So, the question, how to create a "setup-page" that can run a xebium-table before the other pages in a suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a page called SuiteSetUp

http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SpecialPages